# How to CountIf items in ListView VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i have a form that has two listviews,
lv = listview

lv1 from textbox
lv2 countif items from lv1.

my question, how i can count the items in lv1 and show it in lv2.

thank you very much.
:)

Best regards,
HMZ

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ListView1.Items.Add("Buah").SubItems.Add("Apel")
ListView1.Items.Add("Buah").SubItems.Add("Mangga")
ListView1.Items.Add("Buah").SubItems.Add("Jambu")
ListView1.Items.Add("Buah").SubItems.Add("Durian")
ListView1.Items.Add("Buah").SubItems.Add("Rambutan")

ListView1.Items.Add("Sayur").SubItems.Add("Apel")
ListView1.Items.Add("Sayur").SubItems.Add("Apel")
ListView1.Items.Add("Sayur").SubItems.Add("Apel")


Dim firstColDistinctItems() As String = ListView1.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).Select(Function(item As ListViewItem) item.Text).Distinct().ToArray()
For i = 0 To firstColDistinctItems.Count - 1
    Dim repeatCount As Integer = ListView1.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).Where(Function(item As ListViewItem) item.Text = firstColDistinctItems(i)).Count
    ListView2.Items.Add(firstColDistinctItems(i)).SubItems.Add(repeatCount)
Next
```

Comment: Dear Youssef13,
thank you very much, that code is working correctly.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried it, Youssef13's answer should work.

Here's a "more readable" routine that will do just what you want.
Hopefully, the comments are enough to understand how it works.

```
Private Sub CountItems()
    ' Delete any existing items in lv2
    lv2.Items.Clear()

    ' A dictionary that will contain a list of all unique items from lv1 and their occurrence count
    Dim items As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    ' Simple For loop to scan all items in lv1
    For Each itm As ListViewItem In lv1.Items
        If items.ContainsKey(itm.Text) Then ' Check if the item has already been added
            items(itm.Text) += 1 ' In that case, increment its counter
        Else
            items.Add(itm.Text, 1) ' Otherwise, create add it as a new item and set its internal counter to 1
        End If
    Next

    ' Finally, display the dictionary contents in lv2
    For Each itm In items
        lv2.Items.Add(itm.Key).SubItems.Add(itm.Value.ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

UPDATE: Here's a highly optimized (performance-wise) version:

```
Private Sub CountItems()
    lv2.Items.Clear()

    Dim items As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer)) = lv1.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).GroupBy(Function(i) i.Text).Select(Function(i) Tuple.Create(i.Key, i.Count))
    For Each itm In items
        lv2.Items.Add(itm.Item1).SubItems.Add(itm.Item2.ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear xfx,
thank you very much, your code is work.
the result same with youssef13's code and like i mean.

thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your original question to explain what exactly would you want to do with 3 columns?